# Reshaping a keras tensor with one None Dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a keras tensor of shape `(None, 61, 80)` and I want to reshape it to `(61, None * 80)`. The `None` being `batch_size` dimension. I am unable to do using `Keras.backend.reshape`.

I have tried -

```
shape = K.int_shape(x)
G = K.reshape(x, [shape[1], shape[0]*shape[2]])
```

**EDIT 1**

The operation I am trying to perform is HoSVD ( Higher order SVD) on a batch of tensors in a custom layer. For that I have to unfold my tensor in a matrix form.

For example, If i have a batch of tensors of shape (20,61,80) where 20 is the batch size, mode-0 unfolding will give me a matrix of shape (20 , 61*80), mode-1 unfolding will give (61, 20*80) and mode-3 unfolding will give (80, 20*61).

The function which i have written is -

```
def my_unfold(x_tensor,mode=0):
#shape = K.shape(tensor)

num_dims = len(x_tensor.shape)
temp = list(range(0,num_dims))
temp.remove(mode)


change_dims = K.permute_dimensions(x_tensor, [mode ,temp[0],temp[1]])

shape=K.int_shape(change_dims)
new_shape =  K.concatenate(shape[0],shape[1]*shape[2])
G = K.reshape(change_dims, new_shape)
return G
```

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54983295/how-to-use-reshape-keras-layer-with-two-none-dimension) for an answer, perhaps this helps?

Comment: I have tried both . But it doesnt solve my problem

Comment: Can you add more code and a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: What does the `(61, None * 80)` mean? Is your NN a RNN? Please share us more code and explanation.